Why did queries become slower after upgrading SQL Server 2012 to 2022?
I'm in the process of upgrading my current set of databases from SQL Server 2012 to 2022. I've ensured I've matched my resources/specs to ensure both Servers match. I am facing a huge performance decrease in the new SQL Server. Queries that took seconds on 2012 are now taking 10+ minutes in 2022. I've restored the databases from 2012 -> 2022 so the indexes/data are the same. I've also run statistics on all the databases/tables. Set the compatibility to 110 (Server 2012)
I'm at a loss on how to proceed? I could try to tune every individual query but that isn't practical.
I've used Blitz scripts, they have warnings due to my cache being unstable. This is expected since the new database would need to build a cache over time.
It looks like my main wait statistic is Parallelism. Since my server CPU matches the old spec, I'm unsure how to resolve this.
Thank you,
Output of sp_PressureDetector.sql
First screenshot is the 2012 Waits as per Request Erik
Second screenshot is the 2022 Waits. When running the scripts I see CXCONSUMER is the number one wait when troubleshooting a particular query.



I've confirmed all my server settings are the same. I'm getting high amounts of waits for IO, which is odd because we are using the same hardware. The complaint is slowness throughout the new database. I am working with 1 particular query as a test case for now.

@Gautam I'd start from observing select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks wt
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
on wt.session_id = s.session_id
while executing your slow query, what wait do you see in wait_type column?

Hello @sepupic, after running your query the top wait type is CXSYNC_PORT. Also for the pictures above. You can see the wait time on my new server is more or equal to my old server with the uptime being a fraction of what the old one was. Basically I've waited more in the new one then I have in the lifetime of the old one. Thank you for your comment

@Gautam >>>Also for the pictures above. You can see the wait time on my new server is more or equal to my old server<<< There is no such a wait in 2012 just because it was within CXPACKET as well as CXCONSUMER. What is the number of logical processors you are using and what is maxdop you configured?

I still don't have the same performance as my original 2012 database. I'd say I am about 80% there though. I applied the following settings thanks to the people above.

MAXDOP set to 8 (Max per documentation)
LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION ON
Compatibility set to Server 2012
Ran statistics on all tables with full scan option

